# MySQL: Union with fields different order

Tags: mysql, union

I have the following issue:

I have many tables with many common fields and some different ones. I would like to make a union of all these tables and set null the values for columns not in the table.

I tried to do something like this

```
SELECT *,
null as field_table2,
null as field_table3,
...
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT *,
null as field_table1,
null as field_table3,
...
FROM table2
UNION
...
```

The problem is now fields don't have the same order so I see values in different columns.

Is there a way I could do this right?

Thank you

Comment: You will need to explicitly select the columns in the same order from each table.

Comment: Do not use an asterisk, specify separate columns list one-by-one.

Comment: Thank you. 
I hoped I could do it with asterisk